# How to do exact search in Shiny DataTables column

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have the following self-sufficient Shiny script:

```
mydf <- data.frame(commonality=c("common","uncommon","common","uncommon","common"),value=c(1,2,3,4,5))

library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      mydf, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Which produces this:

[image]

What I want to do is to do exact search. For example when I type `common`, 
the values `uncommon` should not appear. How can I do that?

Comment: we can't see the image !

Comment: @R.B Please reload. I can see it in my part. Otherwise please see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/gevKx.jpg

Comment: This is two questions: 1. can the underlying JS widget do what you want [https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()]? and 2. if it can, how can I get the right options through shiny into the resulting JS?

Comment: you can use the filter :
`library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      mydf,filter = 'top', options = list(lengthChange = T)
    )
  }
)`

Comment: @R.B turn that into an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter of the DT package :

```
 library(shiny) 
    shinyApp( ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')), 
    server = function(input, output) { 
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable( mydf,filter = 'top', options = list(lengthChange = T, dom = 'tip') )
      })
```

and the result look like this : [image]

Comment: you can run the search from the filters and it works for me

Comment: is there a way to do it from the default `Search` filter as in my OP?